# find Non-duplicate element array in javascript with filter method

Tags: javascript

i wanna find Non-duplicate element array in javascript with filter method.
for example:
const number = [1,2,1,3,4,5,3];
i wanna find 2,4,5 in array 
please help me

Comment: [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473/3982562)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code snippet: `number.filter(x => number.filter(y => x === y).length === 1)`

### Explanation

Filter out (outer filter) only those numbers from the array which occur (checked using inner filter) exactly once in the array.